# Does the frequency of a PWM signal have to be constant for a DC motor/fan speed control?

Tags: motor, pwm, control

All PWM control systems I have seen for DC motor/fan speed control used a constant frequency. Is this really necessary in all cases?

How would the motor current have to be calculated for a PWM control with a constant or variable frequency?

Comment: It doesn't need to be varied, and it's easier not to?

Comment: +1 to stabilize the fly-by downvote, but we need some more context about what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: This is not a mathematical question, so asking for a mathematical solution is a bit strange.

Comment: The pulse width is a ratio or fraction of the total pulse length. The pulse length is the PERIOD of the signal which is 1/FREQUENCY. Altering the frequency means you have to recalculate or adjust the pulse width to give the same fraction (mark/space) as the original signal but achieves no advantage - its the same average value of current, voltage or power. By keeping the same frequency (PERIOD) all the PWM circuit has to do is alter the pulse width within that period.

Answer (score 3):

The frequency need not be constant, although it often ends up this way because it's easy to implement. One reason to vary the frequency is to spread EMI and audible noise across the spectrum. It's also possible to perform motor control by [hysteresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#Control_systems). Or, the pulse width may be held constant but the frequency varied. Or, both may be varied.

What's really important is average voltage being applied to the motor over time. In the case of a simple DC drive, the average voltage is the same as the voltage applied at any instant. Usually, the voltage switches between 0 and the supply voltage \$Vcc\$, so the average voltage will be somewhere between 0 and \$V_{cc}\$, according to the proportion of time spent on \$t_{on}\$ in some period \$t_{total}\$:

$$ V_{avg} = V_{cc} \frac{t_{on}}{t_{total}} $$

So if over \$100mS\$, you spent a total of \$40ms\$ on, and \$V_{cc}\$ is \$12V\$, then:

$$ V_{avg} = 12V \frac{40ms}{100ms} = 4.8V $$

So, to the extent that the inductance of the motor is able to average the current over \$100ms\$, you might as well have been applying \$4.8V\$ DC to the motor.

This is what sets the lower bound on the drive frequency. If the frequency is too low, the current in the motor windings (and thus, the torque, and thus, the speed) will not be constant. Take an extreme case: you apply 12V for 4 minutes, then 0V for 6 minutes. The average voltage is still 4.8V, but obviously you don't get the same effect.

As the frequency becomes higher, the maximum current (right before switching to the off state) and the minimum current (right before switching to the on state) will not be very different, and the motor current is mostly constant. This is because the rate of change of current \$I\$ in an inductance \$L\$ is limited by the applied voltage \$V\$:

$$ V = L\frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

or equivalently:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{V}{L}$$

Your power supply can apply only a finite voltage to the motor windings (an inductor), so the current can only change so fast. Switch fast enough, and the current never has time to change significantly.

Another way to think of this: The current in the motor will have some DC component, the average value that spins the motor in the desired direction. It will also have some AC [ripple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripple_%28electrical%29) added to that, which just makes heat in the windings since it spends half its time spinning the motor in the desired direction, and the other half in the wrong direction. Your goal, in designing a PWM motor drive, is to reduce the current ripple, and the consequent wasted electrical energy, as much as possible, without increasing other losses in the system.

Another requirement is often that the motor not make audible noise, and this often requires that the switching frequency be above the limits of human hearing, about \$25kHz\$.

The upper bound on switching frequency is set by losses that increase with frequency, primarily switching losses. Transistors can not switch instantly, and so will necessarily spend some time with both significant current in them, and significant voltage across them, thus converting electrical energy into heat (\$P=IE\$) each time they switch. As the frequency is raised, the number of switches per second increases, but the time spent transitioning from *on* to *off* states says the same, so the average power in the transistor increases until the heat destroys the transistor or the driver efficiency becomes unacceptable.

Comment: The main reason to not go too high in PWM frequency is the cost of switching the PWM signal -- power MOSFETs are power hungry when actually switching, and the more often they do that, the more power they draw.

Answer (score 2):

There is a range of frequencies that the system will work well inside.  This range is quite large, but the exact frequencies depends on the motor and what you are trying to accomplish.  But within that frequency range, it doesn't matter what the exact frequency is and it can move around.

For most fans, you want the frequency high enough that you can't hear the PWM rate with your ears.  This usually puts your frequency at higher than 20 KHz (but not always!).

On the top end, capacitors inside the fan can/will put a limit to the max frequency.  The amount of power lost in your MOSFET or power transistor will also increase as the frequency goes higher.  This will limit the maximum reasonable frequency to maybe 100 KHz, although I'm sure there are some systems able to go much higher.

But as some have already said:  it is almost always easier to do a fixed PWM frequency than a variable one.  Most people do fixed frequency because that is the easiest thing.

Comment: The behavior of brush motors at higher PWM rates is qualitatively different from their behavior at power PWM rates, with the dividing line between "fast" and "slow" being the point where the motor's inductance is high enough that the current never drops to zero; the biggest obstacle to using higher speeds is the switching circuitry itself.  To what extent does the commutation circuitry built into typical DC fan motors affect things?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a home work question.

However to add to @JIm comment to the OP. PWM (for anny application) is usually a fixed period because it's easiest to implement in hardware (It does not have to be fixed).

You set values (in a MCU or the hardwired circuit) and forget.

Any maths is to do with the implimentation regarding period, counters, minimum and maximum duty cycles, filtering of the output by a RC network to calculate a DC output and it's ripple if required.